# Did Yitzchak carry out his father's legacy?

Tags: abraham, yitzchak

I had learnt that after Avraham had passed away, people whom Avraham had preached about the monotheism of G-d didn't hold on to the truth but went astray. Why didn't Yitzchak carry his father's legacy teaching people about One G-d?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The answer I heard, I believe from Likkutei Sichos, is that Yitzchak did continue his legacy, and was able to make better progress than his father. It was to do with the wells, his father would use chessed to bring external water to people, but Yitzchak would use gevura to dig wells where the people were i.e. they would internalise the lesson. This method of gevura can't be as large scale though, so he had fewer students. If I find the source, I will write up as an answer bli neder, or hopefully this comment will prompt someone else to find the source or write their own answer. Thanks for this

Comment: interesting question, my follow up is why is Yitzchak not mentioned nearly as much as Avraham or Yaakov either?

Comment: Yea this is also an alltime question for me.. Why one of the Avot were not mentioned much as the other two?

Comment: Although, i had an aswer for this: Since there were no major or important events in Yitzchak's life nothing is mentioned of him even though he lived a righteous life.
But iam not satisfied with this answer, still waiting for a good answer.